# Is this hashing function overkill

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-protection, sha

I recently began work on a project and it contains the following function to hash passwords :

```
function hash_password($password) {
    $account_id = $this->account_id;

    /*
     * Cook up some randomness
     */
    $password = str_rot13($password);

    $random_chars = "1%#)(d%6^".md5($password)."&H1%#)(d%6^&HB(D{}*&$#@$@FEFWB".md5($password)."``~~+_+_O(Ed##fvdfgRG:B>";

    $salt = $account_id;
    $salt = ((int)$salt * 123456789) * 1000;

    $salt_len     = strlen($salt);

    for($i=0; $i <= $salt_len; $i++) {
        $salt .= $random_chars[$i];            
    }

    $salt = str_repeat($salt, 3);

    return hash('sha256', base64_encode($password.$salt.$password), false);
}
```

*$account_id is unique to each user account.

My question is : Is this function any more secure than doing something as simple as :

```
$salt = sha1($account_id);
$hash = hash('sha256', base64_encode($password.$salt), false);
```

Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what hashing algorithm you use, as long as you salt it correctly. Even SHA1 can be pretty secure with a good salt.

Comment: `Is this function any more secure` - well yes, but `Is this hashing function overkill` - definitely yes. You are using *alot* of CPU cycles just to hash the password - which will need to be done *every time* you process a login, or a user changes their password [, or...] whereas what you should be concentrating on more (if they are *that* sensitive) is preventing people from getting hold of the hashed passwords in the first place.

Comment: actually it may be less secure because of much higher entropy - see this https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm - you should use `bcrypt` anyhow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the account ID as a salt is probably not a good idea - if someone can steal your hashed passwords, then they can probably get the account ID's too.  Having a more convoluted hash in code in this instance is therefore probably more secure, provided that the code is also well protected.  Using a known random string as the salt in the code means that someone would have to hack both your data and your code in order to attack passwords - that has to be better than just having to attack the database alone.